System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
I am trying to connect Topsolid Cad software to Visual studio using API,
When I run the code I am geeting error
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
Please see the attached images
enter image description here
I have added all Nuget packeges

The System.IO dependency used in a project is mismatched/incorrect or not loaded.
Solution please ask the developer to remove the dependency library and add it again then clean and build the project
